# ResponseEntity<?> and ResponseEntity are not the same?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I know that raw types are bad in code, and `List<?>` and `List`, for example, are different things. But what about situation with `ResponseEntity<?>` and `ResponseEntity`? Using in `@RestController`.

Comment: At runtime, both are the same. Type information is erased at the runtime. The generics come into effect at compile time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They are actually the same, compiler would replace it with generic type, if you see here in the documentation [ResponseEntity](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html)
it's actually

```
class ResponseEntity<T>
```

so `ResponseEntity<?>` and `ResponseEntity` are the same.

Answer (score 3):

`ResponseEntity<?>` it's kinda trick for IDE, so it's not gonna say you have raw type in your code.

So they are actually absolutely the same, anyway I'd suggest you do not use raw type and provide generic types for any of you response entities.

Answer (score 3):

`ResponseEntity<?>` is read-only. You can not write to it. However, the raw type `ResponseEntity` is writeable.